# How to input query flat output from a different database to a Django model?

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, django-models

First off, I'm new to Django and Python overall - so I might be asking the wrong question, if that's the case please tell me where to look. If not, continue:

I'm working with a Django app that queries a Wordpress database, I have created a connection and wrote the query as such:

```
    cnxn = MySQLdb.connect(host="localhost",
                           user="root",
                           passwd="password",
                           db="dbname") 

    query = '''SELECT post_id, label, meta_value
               FROM table'''
```

The issue is that the data is in a flat format, where the label should be the column name and the meta_value should be the value, output:

```
    post_id    label    meta_value
    -------    -----    ----------
     1         name     example name
     1         email    example@mail.com
     2         name     example name 2
     2         email    example2@mail.com
```

Please keep in mind that there are 24 labels for each post_id, so each form entry adds 24 lines to the table.

How would I got about creating a Django model that appends the data from the table in a pivot style format to be able to display it nicely in the template? The goal is to be able to display 4-5 labels on the main page with a link on each line that shows the full input on a separate page.

Desired output:

```
    post_id        name              email
    -------        ----              -----
       1           example name      example@mail.com
       2           example name 2    example2@mail.com
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I ended up converting the initial output to a pivot using Pandas, then uploaded the df into a new model that I created with the same exact field names.

```
    def users(request):
        df = pd.read_sql(query, cnxn)
        pvt = df.pivot(columns='label', index='post_id', values='meta_value')
        pvt = pvt.reset_index()
        pvt['id'] = pvt.index
        pvt.to_sql('table_name', cnxn, if_exists='replace')
```

The model configured includes all the fields in the queried table, so the outcome matched the model and I can treat it as an object.

Hope this helps.